# multi recepients php mailer

Tags: php, arrays

I've tried to edit a PHP mass mailer that uses PostageAPP.com API call.

However, when I sent a test message to 2 recipients for testing, they see each other's email addresses.

On the documentation site they said:

> As an array. This way recipients only see their own email address:
>
> "recipients" : ["recipient_1@example.com", "recipient_2@example.com"]

But I guess this is not written on PHP.

The default php code is:

```
function some_func() {
    $to = array($_POST['email'] => array('name' => $_POST['variable']));
        
    # The subject of the message
    $subject = $_POST['subject'];

    # Setup some headers
    $header = array(
        'From'      => 'test@email.com',
        'Reply-to'  => 'info@email.com'
    );

    # The body of the message
    $mail_body = 'sample_parent_layout';

    # Send it all
    $response = PostageApp::mail($to, $subject, $mail_body, $header);
    return $response;
}

if (isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] !='') {
    # Processes the form if the email has been entered (see below)
    $response = process_submited_form();
}

$api_key = (POSTAGE_API_KEY == 'ENTER YOUR API KEY HERE') ? null : POSTAGE_API_KEY
```

The html form where I past the email list:

```
<label> To
    <td width="41%"><font size="-3" face="Verdana, Arial, Helvetica,sans-serif">
    <textarea name="email" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea>
</label>
```

Please help me out! I can't send the message to each email manually.

Comment: Are you using the class from the [example](https://github.com/postageapp/example-app-php/blob/master/postageapp_class.inc)? If so youll need to alter the `mail` method to account for multiple recipients.

Comment: Hello, yes i'm using the example. can you please tell me what to change here? if you can take a look into the example source code!! really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Try to submit list of recipients as multiarray.

Try this:

```
$to = array(
      "recipient1@example.com" => array( "name" => "John Doe" ),
      "recipient2@example.com" => array( "name" => "Jim Doe" )
);
```

Or that

```
$to = array(
      "John Doe <recipient1@example.com>",
      "Jim Doe <recipient2@example.com>"
);
```

Replace with email addresses you actually read :)

Comment: If you want to sent blind copies, your best bet to call PostageApp once for every email.

`$recipients = explode("\n\r", $_POST['email'] ); `


Don't forget to go over $recipients array and filter_var each email to validate user input.

Comment: it still shows all the email addresses on the receiver mailbox.
To: xxxx@live.fr, yyyyy@live.fr

Comment: Sorry I guess I clicked Enter in the middle on the writing.

Comment: The idea is to have one multi-line textarea with one address per line.

Comment: thanks . now there is a problem on the code
Catchable fatal error: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string in /home/a1497174/public_html/x/xx.php on line 43

Comment: `$response[] = json_encode( PostageApp::mail($recipient_email, $subject, $mail_body, $header) );`